# Button inside of *ngFor is not firing event

Tags: html, angular

I have the following HTML:

```
<div fxFlex="48px">
    <div *ngFor="let title of levelLabels"
          [style.marginLeft.px]="title.xPosition+16">{{title.label}}<button 
           (click)="test()" style="cursor:pointer"></button></div>
</div>
```

When I click on the button no event is firing. Hovering over the button is not changing the cursor to hand. Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you have used `</div>` extra

Comment: No, my mistake. I dont have extra div.

Comment: `Hovering over the button is not changing the cursor to hand`. That's because you explicitly set it to be a pointer. You may want to remove that or add a `:hover` selector where the pointer is explicitly turned into a hand.

Comment: I removed style but it is still the same. However, my main concern is the click that is not firing.

Comment: the code you provided works as expected: https://angular-ivy-pf8wbi.stackblitz.io

Comment: @Haris. Is it possible to see source code?

Comment: Hi the code you have shared will work with out any error untill some where you have mentioned `pointer-events: none;`. can you please check you CSS

Comment: @Mark I added a link to the stackblitz with the code running

Comment: @Kawinesh. I am using Highcharts. Somewhere in their CCS I see pointer-events: none. Is that the reason why I am NOT getting click event?

Comment: @Mark stackblitz editor link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pf8wbi?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @Mark yes thats the problem :) you spotted it nice :) and use inspect on browser and check if that css is applied to button :)

Comment: @Kawinesh. But I have other buttons in the app that are perfectly clickable.

Comment: @Mark can you inspect the button in browser and paste the CSS properties on it here please :)

Comment: Hmm, I dont even see the button. Nor, I see any labels.

Comment: are you able to see the label ?

Comment: hmmm are you seeing any error in console

Comment: I see both labels and buttons on the screen, but none in the Inspect window. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your button doesn't have anything inside it, so I believe it is actually impossible to hover or click it. Try adding some text in it and see if that works `<button (click)="test()" style="cursor:pointer">Test text</button>` or move your `{{title.label}}` inside the button. Because hovering your div with an empty button inside it will not work.

Comment: Adding text does not do anything.